# Eclipse.ini Configure more than 1024MB

Tags: java, eclipse, flash, ide, flash-builder

I got this JVM.terminated.exit code -1 error while I am setting -Xmx2048m as maximum memory allocation.

How can we set -Xmx2048m in eclipse.ini. My application throws out of memory error in -Xmx1024m configuration. So I should increase the memory size. I attached eclipse error log and eclipse.ini.

Comment: No, you haven't attached anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under Windows 32 bits, the limit is around -Xmx1500m to -Xmx1800m as Windows 32 bit processes have an address space of slightly below 2GB, secondly -Xmx specifies the amount of heap memory available to Java, the java process however requires more memory (for the VM itself, and for the PermGen). As Java requires(/d?) a contiguous virtual memory area, the exact amount of memory it can claim also depends on what other processes have already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You did not paste the error log. The error is most likely because 2G memory is not available. You might want to try a smaller value.